# Selecting dates - javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have a comboBox `DateType` with options `Today, Yesterday, Week-to-date`
I also have 2 textboxes - one for `Start Date` and one for `End Date`.
By default, the `DateType` will be set to `Today`'s date.

For eg.: Let's say, current date is 01/11/2011 (Tues)

```
When DateType : Today
Start Date = 01/11/2011
End Date = 01/11/2011

When DateType : Week-to-date (Note: Each week will be `Sun to Sat`)
Start Date = 01/09/2012 (Sun)
End Date = 01/11/2012 (Current Date)
```

Few Variables:

```
var startDate = new Date(document.getElementsByName('Start Date').value);
var endDate = new Date(document.getElementsByName('End Date').value);
```

I am new to javascript, so could anyone help me frame a function that can modify the `Start Date` and `End Date` based on the DateType selected(as above). 
I need the condition only for `Week-to-date`
The rest would be similar,I guess, so I can frame the remaining conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: javascript's native `Date` is fairly primitive, you might want to look at a library like `Datejs`: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Hmm..been over an hour since I posted this question...no answers yet...is it really that complicated? :)

Answer (score 0):

Download Date JS (http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/list)

### Use following code

```
currentDate = new Date().toString('M/d/yyyy');
lastSunday = Date.today().add(-8).sunday().toString('M/d/yyyy');
document.write("currentDate :"+currentDate+"<br/>");
document.write("lastSunday :"+lastSunday+"<br/>");
```